# How to resizing POPUP.html page from mouse in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

When I click icon from Browser action  my chrome extension show side bar "Popup.html" but it overlap to the website (z index),hides the screen . I want to resize or able to move this POPup window through the mouse in  anywhere of the screen .
I tried the **<"!DOCTYPE html>"** but it does not work . Please suggest me how  do I resolve the resizing issue of the popup  winnow through mouse pointer.

Actually I want to resize the POPUP window  through Mouse pointer (Manual resize). Just mouse over on the border of poup window and drag toward left or right for resizing the window as per my convenient .

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use CSS [`resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/resize) property or change the `height` and `width` of `<body>` via JS dynamically (something like `document.body.style.height = "300px"`).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    html, body {
        resize: both;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>Test</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I tried , it does not help. Actually I want to resize the POPUP window  through Mouse pointer (Manual resize). Just mouse over on the border of poup window and drag toward left or right for resizing the window as per my convenient .

Comment: @Rahul, if you use above html as your `popup` page, have you noticed there is something you can click and drag at the right-bottom corner of the popup?

Comment: @Halibara,Not able to see any effect , if you want the i can attach that sample extension here .